# Preventing a race condition in asynchronous Ajax call

Tags: ajax, asynchronous, bootstrap-4

I am using Javascript below to pull content into Bootstrap-4 popover, and I think that it has a race condition:

```
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        html: true
    ,   content: function () {
            // Pull URL from data-remote-ref of the element that triggered the popover
            var url = $(this).data('remote-ref');
            // Make a temporary element ID for the spinner
            var spinnerId = "loading-id-" + $.now();
            // Initiate an asynchronous Ajax call
            $.get(url, function (data) {
                $('#'+spinnerId).html(data);
            });
            // Return temporary content with the spinner
            return '<div id="' + spinnerId + '">'
                 +     '<div class="spinner-border" role="status">'
                 +         '<span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>'
                 +     '</div>'
                 + '</div>';
        }
    });
});
```

This code fires up an Ajax `$.get` request, and then returns `<div id="loading-id-...">` to be rendered.

At this point, `$('#loading-id-...')` does not exist yet, so the browser starts working on adding it to the page.

If Ajax callback happens before the browser has finished constructing the spinner, `$('#loading-id-...')` inside `function (data)` would yield nothing, so the remote content would never get rendered.

Assuming that my assumptions are correct, and there is no special "magic" built into the browser to prevent race conditions of this kind, is there a way to fix this race condition?